# CSS3 box shadow + JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

When using a complex box shadow like:

```
box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25),
inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
```

I am seeing considerable (unacceptable really) degradation of a jquery slideshow on the same page. All the transitions happen instantaneously.

Is the CSS3 box shadow really that intensive a process? Will I have to choose between decent animations and the style?

Comment: Do you have an example for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using animation of "box-shadow" with CSS3 and, sometimes, programmatically.

Under all good browsers (IE have't tested), animation look smoothly.

Programmatical animation works with about 50 objects at the same time. I don't have any problems with it.